# make non-move UITextField on background of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, user-interface

How to make UITextField on background of UITableView?
I want to set textField in the top and when i scroll tableView my textField don't move.

Something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 100, 30)];
    self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 0, 0, 0);

    [self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([TableViewCell class])];

    [self.view addSubview:self.textField];

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why should not you try UISearchBar?

Comment: @user3182143 i want to understand how to make non-move object on TableView

Comment: It won't move brother.

Comment: Now what result do you get brother?

Comment: it moves @user3182143 with tableView

Comment: you should add the textfield to the navbar titleVIew.

Comment: Did you get the solution now?

Comment: @user3182143 yes, why u so worried about me?)

Comment: I help when you are in struggle brother.

Comment: I updated my answer please check  it brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another solution - besides one suggested in comments:

You can create `UIViewController` with tableView and text field. Assign `delegate` and `dataSource` to the view controller. Pin text field to the top and you have your desired behaviour. You will have to connect `tableView` with `IBOutlets`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set textField in the top change textField frame

From

```
self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 100, 30)];
```

To

```
self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 100, 30)];
self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.textField];
```

Also another solution is add textField to navigation item title.I tried this and it works fine.

```
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 100, 30)];
textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.textField;
```

Comment: it is not a problem to set textField in the top